# jquery Uikit Datepicker automatic fill 7th day from selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am using this plugin: [jquery uikit datepicker](https://getuikit.com/docs/datepicker.html)

i have a form like this:

```
from: <input type="date"> | to: <input type="date">
```

it is possible if i select a date in "from". then it automatically select "to" date.

like today is Thursday  and date is 11/24/2016. if i select "from" date as 11/24/2016. then to date will be 12/1/2016.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code. i think it will work .

```
 $('#first').datepicker({onSelect: function(dateStr) {
                $('#second').datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', dateStr);
          }});
    $('#second').datepicker();
```